# How can we pop back the spliced item into an array based on index after few seconds

Tags: javascript

Once removed an user from array based on the index, then after 5 seconds how can we pop the user back into the same array ? I am getting `undefined` here, could someone please advise

```
const userArray = [
        {
        "Username1": "UserQa",
        "Password1": "testQA"
        },
        {
        "Username2": "UserV3",
        "Password2": "testV3"
        },
        {
        "Username3": "UserStage",
        "Password3": "testStage"
        },
        {
        "Username4": "UserProd",
        "Password4": "testProd"
        }
    ]
    
   console.log( randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds));
     
    function randomUserPickup(userArray, callback) {
     var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*userArray.length );
     console.log("My Index::"+index);
     userArray.splice(index); 
     return callback(userArray);
     
    }
    
    
    function afterFiveSeconds(userArray){
         setInterval(function(){      
           return userArray;
       },5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to StackOverflow so I don't know how to write an answer here properly.

**My Solution**

```
const userArray = [
  {
    Username1: "UserQa",
    Password1: "testQA"
  },
  {
    Username2: "UserV3",
    Password2: "testV3"
  },
  {
    Username3: "UserStage",
    Password3: "testStage"
  },
  {
    Username4: "UserProd",
    Password4: "testProd"
  }
];

function randomUserPickup(userArray, callback) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * userArray.length);
  if (userArray.length < 1) {
    // added a if condition in case there are no users remaining
    console.error("No More user remaining");
    return;
  }
  const randomUser = userArray.splice(index, 1)[0]; //added 1 in splice, since i belive you wanted to extract just one user from here
  
  console.log(randomUser);
  
  callback(randomUser);
  return randomUser;
}

function afterFiveSeconds(data) {
  // use timeout here instead of interval if you want to run this function only once
  setTimeout(function () {
    userArray.push(data);
    console.log(userArray);
  }, 5000);
}

// this function will return random user and after 5 seconds it will add them back
//  And when there are no more user the function will exit with a console error
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
randomUserPickup(userArray, afterFiveSeconds);
```

This Code Outputs a random user object out of your array and then it adds back that user to the original array again.

And if you just want to get a random user from that array then you can ditch the slice method and the 5sec function. And write a simple function just to return a random user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want the array to have the updated list of users each time after  the splice is done. Assume this is the initial array `[ user1, user2, user3, user4] ` but after first splice done..the array list might be `[user1, user3, user4]`  and then again random applied on this list  and splice done... the list might be `[user1, user3]` and when length become 1 no splice needed. Also in every 5 seconds the spliced item will be pushed back into array.